# Display stock remaining quantity for all type of products

Tags: stock, bundled-product, inventory, stock-status, cataloginventory

My requirement is to display stock remaining quantity in PDP for all types of products : **simple,bundle,grouped,configurable.**

For **bundle** products, when I choose the radio button/switch option, the corresponding simple product's stock qty should be displayed.

Comment: I haven't started yet. Though, for simple products I'm able to get the remaining qty. My query is mainly for bundle products, that too change of qty while swapping options.

Comment: I suggest you to go for it first, and once stuck, then share your approach, so that I can reply accordingly.

Comment: Im currently referring this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/34578/get-stock-values-for-bundled-product-in-product-grid

Comment: Sure go for that, and let me know applied, if you face any issues

Comment: Yes Im able to get the child product id's using that reference. From that now i need to get the stock level.

Comment: Got answer from the link given in comments